# Conflict of packages using tikz for two sine waves

Tags: tikz-pgf

So this is my code for a lab report and I get and error saying that my paragraph ended before `\pgfkeys@addpath` ended , I started trying with only de standalone for the documentclass only , then added my other dependencies but when I add the margin and geometry I started to get the error, maybe there's a conflict of dependencies that I'm not seeing, I really appreciate any help :)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,reprint,groupedaddress,standalone,amsmath,amssymb,
aps]{revtex4-1}




\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%compilador
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}%ecribir en español
\usepackage{blindtext}%notacion
\spanishdecimal{.} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}%entorno matemático 
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}%incluir figuras y gráficas de un programa externo 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[paperwidth=215.9mm,paperheight=279.4mm,centering %margenes
%,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lineno} %tipo de papel tamaño (A4)
\usepackage{float} %proceso 
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{amsmath} %trabajar con formulas 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,cancel}
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}%%Bibliografía como sección
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating} %rotar celdas
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\marginsize
{1.5cm}%%izquierda
{1.5cm}%%derecha
{0.5cm}%%arriba
{1cm}%%abajo
\usepackage{esint}%%integrales
\newcommand*\VF[1]{\mathbf{#1}} %
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*{\emm}{0.000005}
\newcommand*{\emmc}{0.00005}
\newcommand*{\cim}{$\pm$ 0.00005}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\textup{Circuito RLC}}
\fancyhead[L]{\textup{Laboratorio de Electrónica}}
\fancyfoot[R]{} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\raggedbottom 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            trig format plots=rad,
            axis lines = middle,
            enlargelimits,
            clip=false
            ]
            \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200,blue] {sin(x)};
            \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200,red] {sin(x-2)};
            \draw[dotted,blue!40] (axis cs: 0.5*pi,1.1) -- (axis cs: 0.5*pi,0);
            \draw[dotted,red!40] (axis cs: 0.5*pi+2,1.1) -- (axis cs: 0.5*pi+2,0);
            \draw[dashed,olive,<->] (axis cs: 0.5*pi,1.05) -- node[above,text=black,font=\footnotesize]{$\Delta t$}(axis cs: 0.5*pi+2,1.05);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: use either `\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla,shorthands=off]{babel}`, or `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the  time for reviewing :)